# Windows directory location of --user-data-dir=remote-debug-profile

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge

I just learned that Edge can have different profile directories. The default one is this one and is used most of the time:

> C:\Users{userName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data

But I could create another set of profiles when I launch the msedge.exe with a **user-data-dir** parameter. For example like this:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
> --user-data-dir=C:\Blub"

If you start edge in this way, you can generate a new set of profiles that are stored in "C:\Blub".

I stumbled across this parameter when I learned how to debug with VS Code.
[This article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging#_attaching-to-browsers) explains that the user-data-dir parameter is also needed for this.
But here you are not using a concrete path, but a value "remote-debug-profile" like this:

> edge.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
> --user-data-dir=remote-debug-profile

Also here a new "set of profiles" can be generated that will only be available when launching Edge with the remote-debug-profile parameter.

I am now curious where those profiles are stored on the disc. I could not find this with google. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to navigate to `edge://version` in Microsoft Edge and view the property `Profile path`. Something like this:

[image]